# Error connecting to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm facing a problem when trying to connect my Node.js application to MongoDB using Mongoose. Whenever I try to start the application, I receive the following error:

"Error connecting to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError:  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
Here is the code snippet I am using to make the connection:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();

const user = process.env.MONGODB_USER;
const pwd = process.env.MONGODB_PWD;
const host = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const database = "todoList";

const connectionString = `mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@${host}/${database}`;

mongoose
    .connect(connectionString, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Conectado ao banco de dados");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados", err);
        process.exit();
    });


I've already checked my MONGODB_USER and MONGODB_PWD environment variables, and they are set correctly. Also, I'm sure the MongoDB server is running.

Alguém pode me ajudar a identificar o que pode estar causando esse erro de conexão e como posso resolvê-lo? Agradeço antecipadamente pela ajuda!
```

Comment: In your post what is "*[specific error message]*"? Is it ECONNREFUSED by any chance?

Comment: the error is  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb

Answer (score 0):

> The getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error indicates that the hostname you have
> provided for your MongoDB deployment cannot be resolved by the client
> you are using.
>
> double-check the details in your connection string and try to ping
> that hostname from the command line to verify the name can be resolved
> to an IP address.

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongoserverselectionerror-getaddrinfo-enotfound/189564